# java compiler annotation processor option not passed correctly

Tags: java, maven, annotation-processor

I am writing a java annotation processor to collect metadata from the annotations in a body of code. I want the output file to start with the maven project version. Looking at the [javac documentation for Oracle java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), it appears I should be able to pass the project version as an option to the annotation processor using the notation `-A key=value`. So I configured the maven-compiler-plugin to set the `core.versionId` option to the project version as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <compilerArgs>
    <arg>-A core.versionId=${project.version}</arg>
  </compilerArgs>
</configuration>
```

However, when I compile, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error compiling: key in annotation processor option '-A core.versionId=1.7.0-SNAPSHOT' is not a dot-separated sequence of identifiers
```

It seems that the project.version was correctly inserted, but the compiler failed to process the -A option as advertised. I must be missing something, but I cannot see what it is, and I can find no mention of this problem. Any help much appreciated.

Update: The error goes away if I remove the space, making the arg be
   `-Acore.versionId=${project.version}`, 
but in this case the core.versionId option does not show up in the annotation processor.

Comment: Did you look it up in your `AnnotationProcessor` with `processingEnv.getOptions().get("core.versionId")`?

Comment: Here's the relevant line:`String artifactVersion = processingEnv.getOptions().get("core.versionId");`

Comment: Did you have a look whether there are any options at all in the Environment?

Comment: The options map appears to be empty.

Comment: After looking at the maven-compiler-plugin page, maybe you have to use `forceJavacCompilerUse`? See: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#forceJavacCompilerUse

Comment: I tried that, saw no change. I tried `<fork>true</fork>`, still no change.

Comment: I tried splitting the arg in two: the -A and the key=value as separate args. That gives a different error message: `javac: -A requires an argument; use '-Akey' or '-Akey=value'`. So if I leave out the whitespace, it compiles without errors, with or without the `fork` option. But without the whitespace, the `getOptions()` map is empty.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that a critical piece of information was omitted from the original question. The module being compiled also needs weaving with AspectJ, which re-runs the compiler. The annotation processor was indeed running and producing its correct output during the compile step, but was being immediately overwritten by a second run of the annotation processor during the AspectJ weaving step. Adding a bit of configuration to the aspectj-maven-plugin clause solved the problem:

```
<configuration>
  <proc>none</proc>
</configuration>
```